# Как сделать custom_title в Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

Не могу установить префикс администратора, подскажите как?

```
@dp.message_handler(commands=["админ1"],commands_prefix="+")
async def ponk(message: types.Message):
    admname = " ".join(message.text.split()[1:])
    adm = message.reply_to_message.from_user.get_mention(as_html=True)
    await bot.promote_chat_member(message.chat.id,message.reply_to_message.from_user.id,can_delete_messages=True,can_pin_messages=True,can_manage_video_chats=True,can_manage_chat=True)
    await message.answer(f"{adm} повышен в статусе‍\n⬛ +удаление сообщений\n⬛ +закрепить сообщение\n⬛ +управление видеочатом\n⬛ +просмотр журнала",parse_mode="html")
    await custom_title(f"{admname}") #префикс админа
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуй так

```
await bot.set_chat_administrator_custom_title(message.chat.id, message.reply_to_message.from_user.id, f"{admname}")
```